# How are incompatible classes with same serialVersionUID handled?

Tags: java, serialization

There are a number of answers explaning the usage of `serialVerionUID`. My question is about the specific situation, where two incompatible versions of a class are used which have the same `serialVerionUID`.

This may happen if you use RMI between a client and a server which have different versions of a class, but the `serialVerionUID` has not changed.

Is there something like: If a property is not needed by the receiving side it's not used. Or if a property is not sent, it remains `null`? What happens if the property type has changed?